# Spin^c structure induced by a spin structure

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles, spin-geometry

I wondered how it works exactly to induce a $\mathrm{spin^c}$-structure if a spin structure is given. I wanted to use the following definitions as used in Friedrich`s "Dirac operators in Riemannian Geometry"

Let $(Q,\pi_Q,M;\operatorname{SO}(n))$ be a $\operatorname{SO}(n)$-principle bundle on a manifold $M$. The maps $\lambda:\operatorname{Spin}(n)\to \operatorname{SO}(n)$ and $\lambda_\mathrm{c}:\mathrm{Spin^c}(n)\to \operatorname{SO}(n)$ below are the respective standard covering maps. The  horizontal arrows are the actions of the groups on the fibers.

**Definition**
A *spin structure* on $Q$ is a pair $(P,\varLambda)$ consisting of a $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$-principal bundle $(P,\pi_P,M;\operatorname{Spin}(n))$ such that $\varLambda:P\to Q$ is a $2$-fold covering bundle map for which the following diagram commutes

[image]

**Definition**
A *$spin^c$ structure* on $M$ is a pair $ (P^{\mathrm{c}},\varLambda_{\mathrm{c}})$ consisting of a $\mathrm{Spin^c}(n)$-principle bundle $(P^{\mathrm{c}},\pi_P,M;\mathrm{Spin^c}(n))$ over $M$ and a fiber map $\varLambda_{\mathrm{c}}:P\to Q$ such that the following diagram commutes:

[image]

Now a typical assertion is that each spin structure induces a canonical $\mathrm{spin^c}$ structure. I tried to show that via connecting the commutative diagrams, and using the fact that there is a natural inclusion of the spin group in the $\mathrm{spin^c}$ group. That means I get a diagram, where the "upper" and "big" part commutes, but I do not know how to define $\varLambda_{\mathrm{c}}$:

[image]

Comment: The point, ultimately, is that $\text{Spin}(n)$ is a subgroup of $\text{Spin}^c(n)$.

Comment: Well, basically I did not explain every map yet, but $\mathsf{i}$ should be the inclusion (which exists because they are subgroups as you said). $P^{\mathrm{c}}$ is the associated bundle $P\times_{\operatorname{Spin}(n)}\mathrm{Spin^c}(n)$.

Comment: Having defined $P^c$ as an associated bundle, you define $\Lambda_c$ as being induced by $\Lambda$ (and the homomorphism $Spin^c(n)\to SO(n)$. Doing this, commutativity of the diagram follows readily.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what the induced map should be. So $\varLambda_\mathrm{c}$ is $P\times_{\operatorname{Spin}(n)}\mathrm{Spin^c}(n)\to Q$ which maps an equivalence class $[p,c]$ to $\varLambda(p)$?

Answer (score 0):

The map $\Lambda_c: P \times _{Spin(n)} Spin^{c}(n) \rightarrow Q$ is given by $\Lambda_{c}([p,c])=\Lambda(p)\lambda_{c}(c).$

Comment: You should add more to your answer to explain your solution so that the OP can understand. Also, you should use Mathjax for formatting.